# before forward slash `/` Any X amount character I want to wrap inside the div/span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner on jQuery. So I need help from your side. I want to write a jquery/javascript function.

before forward slash `/` Any X amount character I want to wrap inside the div/span tag.

Can you help me!

> Current result

```
<p>
<span class="elementor-drop-cap">
<span class="elementor-drop-cap-letter">1</span>
</span>
0/10
</p>
```

> Looking for Final result:

```
<p>
<span class="elementor-drop-cap">
<span class="elementor-drop-cap-letter">1</span>
</span>
<div class="myclass">
<span>0</span>/10
</div>
</p>

var x = jQuery('.elementor-drop-cap-yes p').contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3}).wrap('<span class="drop-caps" />');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Although you have supplied the 'result' & 'desired result' you haven't added the code you wrote which SO contributors will need to provide assistance _ Please add the code

Comment: var x = jQuery('.elementor-drop-cap-yes p').contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3}).wrap('<span class="drop-caps" />');

Comment: @inputforcolor Kindly review